# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError /tmp/javacpp94368173067/ libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: java, opencv, ubuntu, javacv

***I coded for motion detection code in java using javacv ,it is perfectly running on windows but in Ubuntu 13.04 it shows error like this please suggest solutions for this, i'm attaching code also***

**Code**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package demo;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
import com.googlecode.javacv.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_calib3d.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.*;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
        grabber.start();

        IplImage frame = grabber.grab();
        IplImage image = null;
        IplImage prevImage = null;
        IplImage diff = null;

        CanvasFrame canvasFrame = new CanvasFrame("Original stream");
        canvasFrame.setCanvasSize(frame.width(), frame.height());

        CanvasFrame editFrame = new CanvasFrame("Edited stream");
        canvasFrame.setCanvasSize(frame.width(), frame.height());

        CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();

        while (canvasFrame.isVisible() && (frame = grabber.grab()) != null) {
            //cvSmooth(frame, frame, CV_GAUSSIAN, 9, 9, 2, 2);
            if (image == null) {
                image = IplImage.create(frame.width(), frame.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                //cvCvtColor(frame, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);
            } else {
                prevImage = IplImage.create(frame.width(), frame.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                prevImage = image;
                image = IplImage.create(frame.width(), frame.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                cvCvtColor(frame, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);
            }

            if (diff == null) {
                diff = IplImage.create(frame.width(), frame.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
            }

            if (prevImage != null) {
                // perform ABS difference
                cvAbsDiff(image, prevImage, diff);
                // do some threshold for wipe away useless details
                cvThreshold(diff, diff, 64, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

                canvasFrame.showImage(frame);
                editFrame.showImage(diff);

            }
        }
        grabber.stop();
        canvasFrame.dispose();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> sx=158sy=37w=350h=350op7 Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /tmp/javacpp94368173067/libjniopencv_core.so: libopencv_core.so.2.4:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1843)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)     at
>   java.lang.System.load(System.java:1061)   at
>   com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:566)    at
>   com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)   at
>   com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)   at
>   com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.(opencv_core.java:136)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)   at
>   com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)   at
>   com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.(opencv_imgproc.java:97)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)   at
>   com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)   at
>   com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.(opencv_highgui.java:85)
>     at
>   com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber.start(OpenCVFrameGrabber.java:174)
>     at demo1.Demo1.main(Demo1.java:187) Caused by:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_core in java.library.path
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1878)     at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1087)    at
>   com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)    at
>   com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:481)   ... 12 more Java
>   Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it simply means is that it s unable to find the native dependencies. JavaCV uses JNI calls internally to use OpenCV dll's. On windows the dependencies were on path (There can be multiple reasons behind, opencv might be on environment variables or in some resources).

I would recommend going through this for linux: https://code.google.com/p/javacv/

Answer (score 1):

Try the "echo $PATH" command in your terminal and make sure that the path to opencv*.dll files on your machine is there or not.